# How to send a HBITMAP over a socket using WIN32 and C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, bitmapimage

I have created an application where I am required to send the cropped part of an image over a Socket. I have cropped the image using StretchBlt(), I am also able to display and save the cropped image to a bitmap file.

Next, I want to send this cropepd image over a Socket connection. The connection between socket is established, My problem is how to send/ receive this image over Socket since send() and recv() functions require a char *.

One idea, is if I select the HBITMAP to a memDC object than can I send the memDC directly to the remote socket ?

Any easier way to achieve this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass an HBITMAP (which is a HANDLE, a reference pointer in memory) to another machine. You can use the [GetBitmapBits Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144850%28VS.85%29.aspx) to transform the HBITMAP into a byte array and send this byte array using send().

On the other side, you'll have to create another compatible bitmap, and use [SetBitmapBits Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162962%28VS.85%29.aspx) after the recv().

Comment: thanks @Simon: is it equivalent to use GetDIBits() and SetDIBits() ? Documentation says "Note  This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit versions of Windows. Applications should use the GetDIBits function", which set of functions I should use ?

Comment: @TheAmitKumar - It's an old API, but it's still there. I would definitely try it, otherwise Get/Set DIBits is fine.

Comment: one more problem is how do I get the size of HBITMAP ? and if I use the old API than do I need to send the BITMAPHEADERs separately or the byte array returned by the GetBitmapBits() will take care of headers also ?I tried using newer API Get / Set DI bits but clueless about the size and header manipulation. thanks buddy...

Comment: If you pass 0 for cbBuffer and NULL for lpvBits, the function should return the needed buffer size.

Answer (score 2):

Generally sending the raw memory would be a bad idea - even if you guarantee that there's always a windows machine on the other end today, it's not very flexible for the future - what if you want to change to a different platform, or even start using .NET over plain win32?

What I'd recommend doing is saving the cropped image out to a .bmp file, then sending the file over the socket like any other. That way you have maximum flexibility for what you're doing.

Unfortunately, if you're working in C++/win32 outputting a bitmap is a bit of a nightmare. Here's the code to output a bitmap that I knocked together based on a few sources - it uses some of our class members, but you should be able to figure out how to plug in the right values there.

http://pastebin.com/gLw7ykMU

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks @Colen:.. your code sample is really quite helpful. Before I start coding this part of my application one more thing I want to ask. If I open the bitmap file as a binary file and send the char data chunks till the end of file. and At remote side I store this as a bitmap file, will that suffice ?... Act this is not a project this is just an exercise given by manager and (unfortunately) he is just interested in quick output. Will sending the memDC directly is really an option as my manager suggested me in a free talk ?  thanks once again. . .

Comment: honestly don't know the answer to that, sorry. Try it and find out :)